# Graphs with n vertices and m edges

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Which graphs on $n$ vertices and $m$ edges have the  maximal number of independent sets? I was thinking that if $m = \sum_{i=0}^{r} \binom{a_{i}}{2}$, with the $a_{i}$'s maximal and non-increasing, then the graphs with cliques of size $a_{i}$ would be good, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Please use more specific titles. All graphs have $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. Not all graph-theoretical questions are about the maximal number of independent sets.

Comment: The largest possible size of an independent set of a graph on $n$ vertices with $m$ edges is given by $$n+1-\left\lfloor\frac{1+\sqrt{8m+1}}{2}\right\rfloor.$$

Comment: How would this work if $n=5,\ m=7$?  If I'm not mistaken, there is no sequence $a_i$ with $\sum a_i=5$ and $\sum\binom{a_i}{2}=7$  It seems to me that you're on the right track, but some modification is needed.